# Performance issues in iPhone game using HTML and JS, with appMobi

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, canvas, appmobi

I'm making my first game with appMobi after creating some games for Android using Java.
I basically intend to create a endless runner arcade game, 2d, top view.

I'm using appMobi with plain JS and CSS3 (without any other library such as Impact).

I started by doing some tests with canvas and created a very simple demo where you control a ball (basically a circle rendered using canvas) with the accelerometer and need to collect other balls. I've tested it with my Galaxy S2, and an iPhone 4 and it looked like the iPhone ran it much better, so I started writing a simple engine to use dom elements instead.
I basically created an object that connects to a  tag, and holds a position vector, also added a draw function that basically does the following: this.element.style.left=x+'px' (and the same for top and y).

On my main loop i've called the draw function on the objects and updated their location according to my game logic, and re-called the mainLoop using this window.requestAnimationFrame wrapper:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
       return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
              window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
              function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
              };
    })();
```

Then I moved on to creating a camera object to control screen positioning and made it successfully scroll the background using css background-position property.
I've tested it with my new Galaxy s3 and with a s2 with some graphics on (2 200x200 pngs, and a background) and everything ran smooth at ~60 fps.
I was very pleased with the results and really got excited to test on an iPhone 4 iOS 4.x , but to my disappointment it ran at 2-3 FPS ! 30 times slower than my android.
I started making a lot of changes (currently I'm using a viewport of 720x1280) so I've tried using 320*480, using canvas instead, removing scrolling background, resizing images, but to no avail, while the android performed well on all variations.

Best I got was 5 FPS. I got another iPhone to test, an iPhone 4S with iOS5 and got very very unstable FPS. ranged from 3 - 50 but was unplayable - no chances anyone would play it, and I've not even started to pack it with content.

I really want to take advantage of cross-platforming and it would be a shame for me to give up on the Apple market, so any tips or advise will be warmly received!

Thanks,
Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I got on appMobi's forums, if anyone has this issue:

> Use Direct Canvas
>
> JS/CSS3 will perform horrible on every device, no matter what. The
>   stock browser in iOS (Safari) has NitroJS enabled, but not in the
>   UIWebView...but if you have the time, read up and you'll see that you
>   can't write a JS game without tapping into hardware acceleration like
>   Direct Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Find some samples and links to get you started with directCanvas here:

http://www.appmobi.com/documentation/index.php?DOC=DIRECTCANVAS_SDK